# Why would Unique Visitors and Unique Visitors (All Visits) be different in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

The Unique Visitors metric on the Google Analytics home dashboard is showing different values to when 'All Visitors' is selected as an advanced segment of Unique Visitors.

My understanding is that these values should be the same as the segment 'All visitors' is filtering (or in this case, not filtering) the metric of 'Unique Visitors'. Any help with understanding this better?

Also, if anyone knows of a resource where I can find the formulas that Google use for their metrics, that would be greatly appreciated. Figure it's all cloak and dagger but feel like I'm working in the dark.

Comment: Update: this problem only occurs when I've selected other advanced segments (New and Returning visitors). When they're unselected, UV is consistant with 'All visitors selected'.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in how GA counts Visits and how it counts Visitors. That's quite messy thing so better I'd redirect you to some of the detailed descriptions online:

- [Google support - Visits vs. Visitors](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1257084#visits_vs_visitors)
- [Unique visits and visitors](http://www.michaelwhitaker.com/blog/2010/04/23/unique-visitors-0-visits-and-pages-in-web-analytics/)
- [GA Mystery of visitors](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/google-analytics-mystery)

:)